# How do I read a Huge Json file into a single object using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I'm upgrading a backend system that uses `require('./file.json')` to read a 1GB Json file into a object, and then passes that object to other parts of the system to be used.

I'm aware of two ways to read json files into an object

```
const fs = require('fs');
const rawdata = fs.readFileSync('file.json');
const data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
```

and

```
const data = require('./file.json');
```

This works fine in older versions of node(12) but not in newer version (14 or 16)

So I need to find another way to get this 1GB big `file.json` into `const data` without running into the `ERR_STRING_TOO_LONG` / `Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters` error.

I've seen examples on StackOverflow etc. on how to Stream Huge Json files like this and break it down into smaller objects processing them individually, but this is not what I'm looking for, I need it in one `data` object so that entire parts of the system that expect a single `data` object don't have to be refactored to handle a stream.

Note: The Top-level object in the Json file is not an array.

Comment: That works in older versions of node, but not Node16, I get a ERR_STRING_TOO_LONG error on huge Json files.

Comment: All this info is already in the main post, it's a 1024MB+ file, and require/JSON.parse doesn't work.

Comment: Node12 was released in 2019 (Long after that post), it's not a issue there. I don't need to create a string that's huge, just a object that is. (Which works fine in V8)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235340/discussion-between-legiondev-and-evolutionxbox).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [big-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-json) solves this problem.

```
npm install big-json
```

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const json = require('big-json');
 
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('file.json');
const parseStream = json.createParseStream();
 
parseStream.on('data', function(pojo) {
    // => receive reconstructed POJO
});
 
readStream.pipe(parseStream);
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to stream it, so process it in chunks instead of loading it all into memory in a single point in time.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const stream = fs.createReadStream("file.json");

stream.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Comment: I run into the same ERR_STRING_TOO_LONG error.